# Heroku: Rails 3 and rmagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, paperclip, rmagick

I'm seeing the following error when trying to upload a photo for cropping on heroku with the paperclip plugin.

```
Paperclip::CommandNotFoundError
```

I believe I've successfully install rmagick on a rails 3 instance with bamboo as the stack. Why am i seeing this error?

```
has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => {:large => "600x600>",:small => "100x100#" }, :processors => [:cropper]
   attr_accessor :crop_x,:crop_y,:crop_w,:crop_h
   after_update :reprocess_avatar, :if => :cropping?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not a lot of context for this, but how are you uploading/storing the images? Are you using Amazon S3 or some other asset server?

Heroku does not support file storage.

Here is a [sample Rails 2.3 app](http://github.com/pedro/paperclip-on-heroku) showing usage of Paperclip + S3 on Heroku